# How to Remove/Add the width in Clint Side Table using C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am not able to add the HTML table  width in code behind Page.Can you please help me or provide some solution ?

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label id="lblRfpId" runat="server">ID</label>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRfpId" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>

                </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

        table td {
            width: 400px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
   }
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have the class of Html Table.   
 table {
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

            table td {
                width: 400px;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        } 
On asp.net Button click event,i want to remove the table width.

Comment: Please add your html table and code behind to the question to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change tour table tag

```
<table>
```

To

```
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
```

The you will be able to access table in the code behind file.
And then set the Width in the Page Load or wherever you seem fit.

```
tbl.Width = "100%";
```

You could also try with

```
tbl.Attributes.Add("style","width:100%");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this way in javascript basically

```
$("#<%=btn.ClientID%>").click(function(){
    $(this).css('width','auto');
});
```

**UPDATE :** Or you can use like this,i didn't tried this but it is sample code

on your frontend :

```
 function removeWidth(){
        $("#<%=btn.ClientID%>").css('width','auto');
    };
```

and backend :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "removeWidth()", true);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea in c#?I need to do in code behind page.